# Why Component in Angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, components

Why we just use different components in Angular to work in them...

I tried to code without creating components but it didn't worked!

Answer (score 0):

Development using components increases reusability, testability and reliability.

And moreover even if the requirement changes in the future, developer doesn't need to worry about the changes in the entire page, instead he can change only the respective components.

Reusing the components, makes the changes consistent across the application.